# Delete item from JavaScript array with arbitrary numerical indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I'm having trouble figuring how to delete an item from array where the items are indexed in a manner similar to the following:

```
arr[32] = 123
arr[39] = 456
arr[92] = 789
...
```

The two ways I have tried to delete single, specific items from said array have resulted in all items being removed.

---

**Attempted Method #1:**

```
arr.splice(39, 1);
```

**Attempted Method #2:**

```
arr.forEach(function(val, key) {
    if (val == 456) {
        arr.splice(key, 1);
    }
}
```

Now obviously this isn't exactly what my code looks like, but it shows what I've tried well enough. If I am missing any important details, or you want me to pick the code from source to see if it is within the source instead of the methodology, please ask

Comment: so you have a sparsed array and you like to delete an item. what went wrong?

Comment: @NinaScholz "_The two ways I have tried ... have resulted in all items being removed._"

Comment: [Method 1 doesn't remove any other items](https://jsfiddle.net/jfm3x6k4/). And [neither does method 2](https://jsfiddle.net/jfm3x6k4/1/).

Comment: Does your `arr` actually have items with index 0-92 as well, or is `arr` actually an object with keys? Removing an item from the array will change the indexes and could be causing other issues with your logic here.

Comment: As 4castle said, the code doesn't do what you claim. Please add a snippet, with which we can re-produce the issue.

Comment: You should be using a `Map` if your environment supports ES6, otherwise an `Object`. _This is not how arrays are intended to be used in JavaScript._

Answer (score 2):

While splicing changes the length of the array and the given array seems to rely on indices, you could just set the item to `undefined`.

```js
var arr = [];

arr[32] = 123;
arr[39] = 456;
arr[92] = 789;

arr[39] = undefined;

console.log(arr[92]);
```